# How do i configure ssl experation monitoring in nagios core in ubuntu

Tags: ssl, nagios

I have installed Nagios core  4.4.5 version in ubuntu 18 and now I just want to monitor the SSL expiration of my remote server, So how do I configure SSL plugin in Nagios server

Comment: Check -C option at https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html - the third example in "Examples" section is what you might need.

Answer (score 0):

A while since I tried it but I think something like this should work:

Command definition:

```
define command{
    command_name check_cert
    command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -S \
        -I $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 5 -c 10 -p $ARG1$ -C $ARG2$
}
```

Service definition:

```
define service {
  service_description            SSL expiration
  host_name                      your-remote-server
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  check_named_cert!443!21!www.example.net
}
```

I also think I played around with some plug-ins.